# Como recorrer una tabla pivot?

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

tengo una 2 tablas alumnos y empresas, la relación es *Un alumno puede trabajar en muchas empresas y una empresa puede tener muchos alumnos* por consiguiente da como resultado una tabla pivot **alumno_empresa**. Esta tabla pivot tiene mas datos adicionales independientes, al hacer el insert en la tabla ya funciona pero como puedo recorrer o visualizar los datos de esta tabla?

Mi modelo alumno

```
class Alumno extends Model {
public function empresas()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Empresa::class)->withPivot('fechaIncio',
   'fechaConclusion','tipoSupervisor','supervisorNombre','fechaReconocimiento');


}
}
```

Mi modelo empresa

```
class Empresa extends Model{
public function alumnos()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Alumno::class)->withPivot('fechaIncio','fechaConclusion',
   'tipoSupervisor','supervisorNombre','fechaReconocimiento');
}
}
```

intento hacerlo accediendo a un dato de la siguiente manera:

```
$alumno = App\Alumno::findOrFail(1);
return $alumno->empresa->pivot->fechaIncio;
```

pero genera el siguiente error

> Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: ¿Esto está bien escrito así: `fechaIncio`? ¿No falta una `i` por todas partes? Si no es ese el problema, indica por favor cuál es la línea del error. ¿Qué muestra un `var_dump($alumno);`?

Comment: en escritura si falta, pero en bd de la  columna esta escrita de esa manera

Comment: Retorna algo asi `object(App\Alumno)#256 (26) { ["connection":protected]=> string(5) "mysql" ["table":protected]=> NULL ["primaryKey":protected]=> string(2) "id"  ["keyType":protected]=> string(3) "int" ["incrementing"]=> bool(true) ["with":protected]=> array(0) { } ["withCount":protected]=> array(0) { } ["perPage":protected]=> int(15) ["exists"]=> bool(true)["wasRecentlyCreated"]=> bool(false) ["attributes":protected]=> array(5) { ["id"]=> int(1) ["name"]=> string(13) "Luis Fernando" ["description"]=> string(102) "Estudiante de TIC'S,.`